# Size categories not working for Accessibility adjust image size for UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiaccessibility, dynamic-type-feature

I have a UIButton with an image (not background image) that I want to scale when the phone uses large text.

Currently I have set the `adjusts image size` in the XIB to achieve this:

[image]

Here comes the strange thing:

When I set the text size to be above a certain mark the image scales and becomes larger as you would expect.

[image]

If though I take it to the size below it then reverts back to the regular text size:

[image]

It is worth noting the images in question are the `star` image and the `info` image. Please ignore the tram image on the left.

### What have I tried?

- I have looked at the constraints - these don't appear to be having an impact. The buttons are fixed height and width 44 x 44 pixels but this is enough space for the image to get large inside the bounds (the normal image size is only 20x20)
- I have tried setting the values in code:

```
@IBOutlet private var infoButton: UIButton! {
    didSet {
        infoButton.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
        infoButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }
}
```

But this doesn't fix it either

- I have tested this on real device and simulator on various OSs (iOS 11, 12 and 13) and this seems to occur with all of them.

It might be that this is just a bug with Apple - if so c'est la vie, but it seems really weird that this seems to kick in when the size class changes from `.extraExtraExtraLarge` to `.accessibilityMedium`.

- When I reduce the font size the image does then reduce size as one would expect - this shows me that there are appropriate size classes for the image to go to but that it is not hitting them.
- It is interesting that these buttons do not have text and I found an answer that implied the size class is taken from the title of the button and applied to the image - why then does it work sometimes and not others?

Any help or advice very appreciated

Comment: Your image size will change only in the range of a11y size classes.

Comment: Why would the image size only change with size classes above .extraExtraExtraLarge? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: The link definitely seems to contain the information I am after, I am just struggling to find the exact bit. I am already using vector scales images (single scale) so am unsure if I will have to use large content viewer (not ideal) as I feel I am already doing everything in the graphical element size section already.

Comment: The section on graphical element size does not document smoothly enlarging images between .medium and .extraExtraLarge. If it does then I have not found the appropriate section. It only shows how to allow them to be dynamic (which is what I am currently doing).

Answer (score 0):

> Why would the image size only change with size classes above `.extraExtraExtraLarge`? That doesn't make sense.

As your screenshot shows up in your question, you ticked the `Adjusts Image Size` that only deals with `Accessibility`.

The Xcode interface may not be well understood but it clearly states that images can be adjusted **only for the  five largest Dynamic Type sizes** that deal with accessibility ⟹ explained in the *[Building Apps with Dynamic Type](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html#Images)* WWDC video ([22:47](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/245/?time=1367)) for a reliable source.

If need be, there's a [nice detailed way](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#graphical-elements-size) to introduce images in Xcode to be sure they can be enlarged as smoothly as possible.

I hope you have now a better understanding of how the size categories work to adjust the image size in your button.